# Call an external api in .net core 5 application

Tags: asp.net, api, rest, asp.net-core, .net-core

I created a web API application for public holidays.

Here is the class `Pho`

```
public class Pho
{
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public string localName { get; set; }
    public string countryCode { get; set; }
}
```

Here the code I tried to call the API

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://date.nager.at/api/v3/PublicHolidays/2017/FR");
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(""))
    {
        var responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return Ok(responseContent);
    }
}
```

It didn't work and I didn't know how to fix it

Comment: _"It didn't work"_ What does this mean? How didn't it work? Did you get any errors or exceptions?

Comment: On a side note: Change `var responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;` to `var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`.

Answer (score 0):

try to fix uri

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://date.nager.at"); 
using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("/api/v3/PublicHolidays/2017/FR"))
{
   if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
   {
    var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     return Ok(responseContent);
    }
return BadRequest("status code "+response.StatusCode.ToString());   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One of the possible reasons your code is not working is because you're trying to set BaseAddress when the client hasn't been initialized yet.

To add BaseAddress at the time of intializing HttpClient you should do it this way:

```
   var client = new HttpClient
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri("https://date.nager.at/api/v3/PublicHolidays/2017/FR")
            };
            
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress))
            {
                    var responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    return Ok(responseContent);
            }
```